# Extracting just Month and Year from Pandas Datetime column in a .csv file(Python)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
OrderDate
2/1/2018
3/1/2018
3/1/2018
3/1/2018
2/1/2018
3/1/2018
3/1/2018
3/1/2018
3/1/2018
3/1/2018
3/1/2018
3/1/2018
3/1/2018
3/1/2018
2/1/2018
```

The format of the date is `%d/%M/%Y`. When i changed the string `Orderdate` to `Datetime`, the day becomes the month while the month becomes the day. How do i fix the error.

This is the code i use to change the format -> `df['OrderDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['OrderDate'])`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
df['OrderDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['OrderDate'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
df['OrderDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['OrderDate'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
print df
```

## output:

```
  OrderDate
0   2/1/2018
1   3/1/2018
2   3/1/2018
3   3/1/2018
4   2/1/2018
5   3/1/2018
6   3/1/2018
7   3/1/2018
8   3/1/2018
9   3/1/2018
10  3/1/2018
11  3/1/2018
12  3/1/2018
13  3/1/2018
14  2/1/2018
```

For more info refer this link : [Pandas to DateTime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime)